# Child class of SurfaceView crashed the application

Tags: android-layout, surfaceview

I did simple application. I had added the new class TouchView:

```
package com.example.lookatme;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class TouchView extends SurfaceView{

    public TouchView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

}
```

... and added my new view at layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".BlockerActivity" >    

    <com.example.lookatme.TouchView
        android:id="@+id/tvPaint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivCenter"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCenter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:contentDescription="TODO"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

At the start crashed application on the code setContentView(R.layout.activity_blocker) in activity. That i did wrong? The LogCat have same text:

```
10-23 18:02:03.442: W/dalvikvm(1964): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb57ef4f0)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lookatme/com.example.lookatme.BlockerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.SurfaceView
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.SurfaceView
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at com.example.lookatme.BlockerActivity.onCreate(BlockerActivity.java:67)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-23 18:02:03.442: E/AndroidRuntime(1964):     ... 11 more
10-23 18:04:01.741: W/ActivityThread(2020): Application com.example.lookatme is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
```

Comment: In your xml file, why are you putting `com.example.lookatme.TouchView` before `ImageView`?

Comment: I had think that sequence of view can help me and  tried to resort two views. Decision is negative too. But when did deleted TouchView or when simple SurfaceView don't throw any exceptions.

Comment: That's right. From the error log, it says you have been casting the SurfaceView in an incorrect way.

Comment: ok. how can I it change? who and that I need to do?

Comment: Since you haven't provided the source of `BlockerActivity`, all we can say is that you're incorrectly trying to cast a view to a SurfaceView on line 67.

Answer (score 0):

I did found the desision: for child class need to overload other constructor: with Context and Attributes.